# NFS change ownership issue

Tags: permissions, rhel, nfs

We are accessing `NFS mounts` across three hosts. The issue for us is that when we change the ownership of a directory on `NFS mount` on the server, the ownership changes are not taking place on the client. It is getting changed to `nobody` on the client. The issue can be seen for a particular user , for other users it is working fine. The user in question is the following user.

```
$ id contentmanager
uid=506(contentmanager) gid=500(admin) groups=500(admin)
```

`UID` is same on both client and server machines.

Also, if we change the ownership to `contentmanager` manually on the client, it is getting changed to `nobody` user. But if changed to some other user, it works fine.

Please find /etc/exports for the particular directory on the server.

```
/shareddata/share       *(rw,no_root_squash,sync)
```

On the client machine, it is mounted as follows

```
lnxq-004:/shareddata/share  /data/share  nfs   vers=3,rw   0  0
```

Example on the Server:

```
$ sudo chown contentmanager test
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r--  1 contentmanager admin    0 Aug 20 23:08 test

$ ls -ln test
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 506 500 0 Aug 20 23:08 test
```

Example on the Client:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r--  1 nobody admin    0 Aug 20 23:08 test

$ ls -ln test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 99 500 0 Aug 20 23:08 test
```

This is the issue where the ownership is not getting changed to `contentmanager`

Comment: What does `id nobody` show on the client?

Comment: ]$ id nobody
uid=99(nobody) gid=99(nobody) groups=99(nobody)

Comment: from the server:    $ id nobody
uid=99(nobody) gid=99(nobody) groups=99(nobody)

Comment: Can you run `ls -ln` on the client and server?

Comment: Server$ ls -ln /shareddata/share
total 32
drwxrwsr-x 25 500 500 4096 Aug 21 20:46 web
------------                                                                                           Client$]$ ls -ln /data/share
total 32
drwxrwsr-x 25 500 500 4096 Aug 21 20:46 web

Comment: Can you run `ls -ln test` on the client and server ? I'd like to see the numeric uid of the file the client thinks I'd owned by nobody.

Comment: server$$ ls -ln test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 506 500 0 Aug 20 23:08 test
client$$ ls -ln test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 99 500 0 Aug 20 23:08 test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved. The issue was that we changed the `uid` of `contentmanager` user on all client machines so that `uid` is unique.

The issue looks like was  idmapd had cached the earlier `uids` . Clearing the `NFS cache` on all client machines resolved the issue.

```
sudo nfsidmap -c
```

Comment: I did this... and now the uid's and gid's of the files on the client are nobody.  and I see a logged errors name 'user@localdomain' does not map into domain 'nisdomain'.    Arrrgghhhhh!   'hostdomain' is the domain of the machine